How to place anchor tag inside <mat-expansion-panel-header> to avoid a11y issue
I have a structure like this (notice the anchor tag placed inside mat-expansion-panel-header):
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        ...
         <a href="url"/>

      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

In the rendered UI, Angular adds role="button" to mat-expansion-panel-header which causes a11y issue:

Interactive controls must not be nested

This is because anchor tag shouldn't be inside an element with role="button"
How do I resolve this?

The header is a control; why are you putting an anchor in it?

It's a legacy code. But I see that it's an expandable - collapsible element and there's a lot of content in it:  some texts, description along with anchor tag (which is to redirect to another page)

The content (along with the anchor tag) is inside the header itself so that a user could directly click on it

The   `` is marked as a button, but is it actually a button ? does something happens when clicking on it ? my answer will be dramatically different depending on if you answer yes or no to that question. To make it short: if no, simply remove role=button and tabindex=0 and you are good; but if yes, you will need to think your code differently in order to avoid nested focusable/interactive elements completely.

@QuentinC  just a header portion in an accordion and that is clickable. If you click, the content inside expands and click again it collapses. It’s getting added by default in Angular so can’t remove.

OK, so if you want to fix the problem, your best play is to reduce the clickable zone.
For example, make only <mat-expansion-panel-header> clickable instead of the whole <mat-expansion-panel>.
Side question: what is the accessible name or label of the element to be clicked allowing to expand/collapse? There appear to be none really, so your thing is probably not screen reader accessible.

@QuentinC So the header itself contains the link along with other information. When we click the header, it opens another panel below it with further information. For the side question, it’s the header itself <mat-expansion-panel-header> that when clicked opens up (or collapses) the panel.

I don't know well what to say other than you shouldn't make a so big region with as many content clickable and the sole way to expand the hidden content. You should probably rethink your UI completely to make it accessible. I don't see any easy solution.

If you want me to explain why I think there is no easy solution without a complete refactor, I can post a regular answer. I haven't done it by default as this wouldn't be a real answer to your original question.

If you need to have interactive elements inside your options, consider using the Grid Pattern
